# Convert Hibernate persistable object to SQL Insert Statement

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

Is there a way to convert a Persistable object into an SQL Insert Statement using Hibernate? This has to be possible because thats what Hibernate does behind the scenes, But I just need to write out the SQL Stmt to a log file for error handling purposes in cases where the Database goes down and the saving of the Hibernate Object failed.

Comment: Just because Hibernate does it - generates SQL statements - behind the scenes does not mean that what you are looking for is supported. Hibernate's goal is to manage the lifecycle of your objects in a SQL database; it is not a SQL generator.

Comment: You need a jdbc proxy driver and this question is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403361/how-to-intercept-the-hibernate-generated-sql/3403571#3403571

Answer (score 1):

This is a build in feature. You are able to configure hibernate logging to do that:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, SQL_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

[see here.](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html)
Edit: If you want to see the parmeter values maybe you can use [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/). I haven't tried but if it is usefull please post your experience.

Comment: But this gives me SQL Statements in a PreparedStatement Format with "?" instead of the params. I am looking for something that will write a ready-to-execute SQL out to log, that can be then picked up and executed.

Comment: I wouldn't really call this a "built-in feature", as it's just something that is logged for debug purposes. A built-in feature would have Hibernate exposing this programatically for you to access.

Comment: +1 for P6Spy link. This should show the statements with actual values.